# How to make "call to action" in image listview in android when where is only one element in list?

Tags: android, call-to-action, listview

This is typical listview with big image representing one element in list.
Problem is that most test users where didn't event try to click on image (to go to next activity(page)). I tryed to put an arrow like in image but it does not look good and it android design guidelines say it is antipattern. Most of users will have one element in list. How to indicate that element is clickable?
This is what I tried, but I'm not happy how it looks, and not sure this is best approach.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I made arrow to look more like button:
[image]

Comment: I think that is clear that the element is clickable, but the design looks strange to me. I would suggest making it look more like a button. Try black background color with white font, according to rest of your design. Also, give some right margin to the arrow and possibly make it bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have a call to action. You have a button.

When I look at this image, I see a name and a price.

What am I actually looking for? Is this a rental? Can I buy this?

If it was a rental, a call to action may be "Book now and rent for $XX a nite -> "

This  helps me by:

a) telling me what the link is

b) uses words that invoke action, and or create a sense of urgency.

I also find the white/image text low contrast. I would suggesting adding a background. If you can not control what the image will be, white text will no be a good idea.

Since this is the only item, you need to let users know this.
In it's current state, it appears that the page is not done loading.

Try showing a showing **1 of X** count under neath the image. Also, try adding a subtle background color, the large amount of white space is actually very attention grabbing, and I find it calls my attention more than the image.  Reducing the color contrast here will help bring focus to your single item.